# Java Generics, detecting out of range bytes

Tags: java, generics, byte

I'm trying to better understand Java Generics so I put together a small method which takes in a number (a Generic type that extends Number) and simply displays it back.

So what happens is that if the you attempt to pass in a boolean, String or any other 'non number' into the method, the compiler will recognise this and give you a compilation error.  This works great.

As expected, I noticed that when I was sending in a number too large for a certain type (for example 398457385 as an int) the compiler would throw an error. However, it gives no such error when trying to send in a byte that is out of range.  Therefore, I about checking it and throwing an error dynamically as the code ran.  That is where I ran into this problem.

So, I'm having some issues with when sending in out of range bytes. As far as I'm aware, to send a byte into a method as an argument, you must cast it like for example:

> (byte) 200

I would like to be able to detect when the byte is out of range (less than -128 or greater than 127).  Can this be achieved?

My method is below - please note I'v removed all the other 'types' (such as Integer, Long, Float etc...) to simplify the code for the purpose of this question.

**Results:**

```
//These work fine

printNumber((Byte) 100);  //Output: Byte is: 100
printNumber((Byte) 127);  //Output: Byte is: 127
printNumber((Byte) -128); //Output: Byte is: -128

//With the following, I'm trying to get the method to display the 'Sorry, that byte out of 
//range' message. However, sending in the following values yields these results:

printNumber((Byte) 200)   //Output: Byte is: -56
printNumber((Byte) -300)  //Output: Byte is: -44
```

**Here is the method:**

```
static<T extends Number> void printNumber(T params){

    String myString = params.toString();               

    if(params.getClass()==Byte.class){
        Byte num = Byte.valueOf(myString);

        if(num>=Byte.MIN_VALUE || num<=Byte.MAX_VALUE)
            System.out.println("Byte is: "+num);

        else{
            System.out.println("Sorry, that byte out of range");
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: How do you expect an object of type `Byte` to hold a number that exceeds the maximum size of `Byte`? The moment you cast it, it will be lost. This is called a narrowing conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per section [5.1.3 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3), a narrowing cast like this will simply discard all but the 8 least significant bits.  So that `(byte)200` cast would keep the bits that would represent `-56`, discarding the rest.

If you want to perform this kind of bounds check, you will need to do so prior to casting it to a `byte`.